# Como buscar os valores apenas das checkbox selecionadas em codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, checkbox

Tenho checkbox dinâmicas, e queria ir buscar os valores das que forem selecionadas, como fazer isso com codigniter:

Model para ir os campos e criar as checkbox necessárias:

```
public function apoioPertendido(){      
    $query = $this->db->get('tblapoio');        
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

Controller para enviar para a vista os resultados do model:  (tem mais campos que apresentei no model)

```
public function proporEvento(){

            $natureza = $this->evento_model->naturezaEvento();
            $apoio = $this->evento_model->apoioPertendido();
            $espaco = $this->evento_model->espaco();
            $material = $this->evento_model->material();
            $suportgraf = $this->evento_model->suporteGrafico();
            $audiovisual = $this->evento_model->audioVisual();                  

            $data['title']              = 'Propor Evento';
            $data['naturezaEvento']     = $natureza;
            $data['apoioPertendido']    = $apoio;
            $data['espaco']             = $espaco;
            $data['material']           = $material;
            $data['suporteGraf']        = $suportgraf;
            $data['audioVisual']        = $audiovisual;

            $this->load->view('cliente/clienteheaderdash_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('cliente/clientemenu_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('cliente/clienteproporevento_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('cliente/clientefooterdash_view', $data);
        }
```

View do formulário e rotina para escrever as checkbox existentes:

```
<label>Apoio Pertendido</label>
          <div class="form-group">
                 <?php foreach ($apoioPertendido as $row) { ?>
                 <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="<?php  echo $row->tag ?>" value="<?php   echo $row->idApoio  ?>"/> <?php   echo $row->descricao;  ?>
                   </label>
                   </br>
                <?php }  ?>
          </div>
```

Este formulário está a ser enviado para a função fase2 num controlador onde faz a validação de alguns campos e vai para o model:

```
public function etapa2(){
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('naturezaEvento', 'naturezaEvento', '|required|');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('datainicio', 'datainicio', '|required|');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('horainicio', 'horainicio', '|required|');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('datafim', 'datafim', '|required|');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('datainicio', 'datainicio', '|required|');


            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $this->index();
                }else{

                $this->evento_model->etapa2();
                }
        }
```

Neste model etapa2 guardo os campos por post que vêm do formulário, julgo que seja aqui que devo fazer uma rotina para saber os campos que estão presente como as checkbox que forem selecionadas pois só essas me interessam

```
public function etapa2(){
    $data = array(
        $apoiopertendido = apoioPertendido();

        'naturezaEvento'=>$this->input->post('naturezaEvento'),
        'datainicio'=>$this->input->post('datainicio'),
        'horainicio'=>$this->input->post('horainicio'),
        'datafim'=>$this->input->post('datafim'),
        'horafim'=>$this->input->post('horafim'),                        
        );      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Na sua view:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="<?php  echo $row->tag ?>" value="<?php   echo $row->idApoio  ?>"/> <?php   echo $row->descricao;  ?>
```

Altere para

```
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="apoio[]" value="<?php   echo $row->idApoio  ?>"/> <?php   echo $row->descricao;  ?>
```

As checkbox selecionadas estarão na variável como um array:

```
$apoio = $this->input->post('apoio');
```

Recomendo usar `json_encode($apoio);` para salvar as informações do array na base de dados.

Comment: obrigado, no entanto não quero gravar na base de dados ainda não, quero apenas escrever os valores para depois o utilizador confirmar o que escolheu, no entantonão etou a conseguir escrever o que vem do array, alias acho que ele está vindo null :/